# Custom StreamLoader of LiipImagineBundle never instantiated

Tags: symfony, google-cloud-storage, liipimaginebundle

My images are stored in google cloud storage. It has been done through `VichUploaderBundle` and `KnpGaufretteBunlde`with success. Below is how I configured them:

## Services

```
services:           
    app.google_cloud_storage.service:
        class: \Google_Service_Storage
        factory: [Minn\AdsBundle\Factory\GoogleCloudStorageServiceFactory, createService]

    minn.liip_imagine.cache.resolver.gcs:
        class: Minn\AdsBundle\Resolver\GoogleCloudStorageResolver 
        arguments:
            - @logger            
            - @app.google_cloud_storage.service
            - '%bucket%'
            - 'public-write'
```

## knp_gaufrette and vich_uploader config

```
knp_gaufrette:
    stream_wrapper: ~
    adapters:
        motors_adapter:
            local:
                directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/files/motors
        gcsmotors_adapter:
            google_cloud_storage:
                service_id: 'app.google_cloud_storage.service'
                bucket_name: '%bucket%'
                options:
                    directory: motors

    filesystems:
        motors_fs:
            adapter:    motors_adapter
        gcsmotors_fs:
            adapter: gcsmotors_adapter

vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    storage: gaufrette
    mappings:
        motors_file:
            uri_prefix:         motors
            upload_destination: gcsmotors_fs
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid 
            delete_on_remove: true
```

Now, I need to read my images form the google cloud storage through `LiipImagineBundle`. Unfortunately, Google Cloud Storage is not supported by `LiipImagineBundle`. So, I tried to implement a Google Cloud Storage Resolver in similar way as specified [here: Custom cache resolver](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/cache-resolvers.html). Below is how I configured my resolver:

```
minn.liip_imagine.cache.resolver.gcs:
    class: Minn\AdsBundle\Resolver\GoogleCloudStorageResolver
    arguments:
        - @logger            
        - @app.google_cloud_storage.service
        - '%bucket%'
        - 'public-write'
    tags:                                                                                                                                                                                 
         - { name: monolog.logger, channel: tester } 
         - { name: 'liip_imagine.cache.resolver', resolver: 'gcs' }
```

The resolver is instantiated when ever there twig call for an image. It checks if the images is stored or not *(the function `isStored($path)` is called and logger is telling that)*!  The function `resolve($path, $filter)` and `store(BinaryInterface $binary, $path, $filter)` **are never called**. Strange! I say this may be because the data loader is not working properly. So, I created a new data loader which is defined as follows:

```
minn.liip_imagine.binary.loader.stream.gcsmotors_fs:
    class: Minn\AdsBundle\Loader\GCSStreamLoader
    arguments:
        - @logger
        - gaufrette://gcsmotors_fs/
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: tester } 
        - { name: 'liip_imagine.binary.loader', loader: 'stream.gcsmotors_fs' }
```

Guess what? The custom data loader is never instantiated! Have I missed some thing?

Thanks.

---

## Resolver and Data loader

```
<?php

namespace Minn\AdsBundle\Resolver;

use \Google_Service_Storage;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\ResolverInterface;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Binary\BinaryInterface;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Exception\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\NotStorableException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Description of GoogleCloudStorageResolver
 *
 * @author Mohamed Amine Jallouli <jallouli.med.amine@gmail.com>
 */
class GoogleCloudStorageResolver  implements ResolverInterface {

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var Google_Service_Storage
     */
    protected $service;

    /**
     * @var \Gaufrette\Adapter\GoogleCloudStorage
     */
    protected $adatpter;

    /**
     * @var \Gaufrette\Filesystem
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $bucket;

    /**
     * @var string
     */

    protected $acl;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $getOptions;

    /**
     * Object options added to PUT requests.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $putOptions;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $cachePrefix= null;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $key= null;

    /**
     * Constructs a cache resolver storing images on Google Cloud Storage.
     *
     * @param LoggerInterface        $logger     monolog logger.
     * @param Google_Service_Storage $service    The Google Cloud Storage API. It's required to know authentication information.
     * @param string                 $bucket     The bucket name to operate on.
     * @param string                 $acl        The ACL
     * @param array                  $getOptions A list of options to be passed when retrieving the object url from Google Cloud Storage.
     * @param array                  $putOptions A list of options to be passed when saving the object to Google Cloud Storage.
     */
    public function __construct(
            LoggerInterface $logger,
            Google_Service_Storage $service,
            $bucket, 
            $acl,
            array $getOptions = array(),
            array $putOptions = array()
            ) {        
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->service = $service;
        $this->bucket = $bucket;
        $this->acl = $acl;
        $this->getOptions = $getOptions;
        $this->putOptions = $putOptions;

        $this->logger->info( "__construct: bucket=".$bucket);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cachePrefix
     * 
     */
    protected function setCachePrefix($cachePrefix){
        $this->logger->info("cachePrefix= ".$cachePrefix);
        $this->cachePrefix = $cachePrefix;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setKeyCachePrefix($path){
        $pos=  strpos($path, "/");
        $tmp=$path;
        while($pos!==false ){
            //$this->logger->notice("getKey [path=$path , pos=$pos" );
            $path = substr($path,$pos+1);
            $pos=  strpos($path, "/");
        }
        $this->logger->notice("getKey: key=".$path );
        $this->key = $path;

        $this->setCachePrefix(substr($tmp, 0, strpos($tmp, $path)-1));
        //$this->logger->notice("getKey: cachePrefix=". substr($tmp, 0, strpos($tmp, $path)-1));
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function isStored($path, $filter){
        $this->logger->info("isStored? =  path=$path , filter=$filter");
        return $this->objectExists($path, $filter);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function resolve($path, $filter){
        $this->logger->info("resovle: path=$path , filter=$filter");
        return $this->getObjectUrl($path, $filter);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function store(BinaryInterface $binary, $path, $filter){
        $this->logger->notice("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- store() -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*");
        $this->setKeyCachePrefix($path);

        // Creation of the $adatpter
         $this->adapter = new \Gaufrette\Adapter\GoogleCloudStorage(
                 $this->service,
                 $this->bucket, array(
                     'directory'=>$this->cachePrefix .'/'. $filter,
                     'acl'=>$this->acl), true);

         // Creation of the $filesystem
         $this->filesystem = new \Gaufrette\Filesystem($this->adapter);


         // I assume here that the file is already in the bucket. That's why, a BinaryInterface is given.
         // Consequently, Binary will be directly re-written in the bucket according to its filter.

         // let's log a little bit out store() function to know what is happening!
         $this->logger->info('store: key='.$this->key);
         $this->logger->info('store: filter='.$filter);
         $this->logger->info('store: binary='.$binary->getMimeType());

        try {
            $this->filesystem->write($this->key, $binary);
            $this->logger->info('store: filtered image='. $this->getObjectUrl($path, $filter));

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logError('The object could not be created on Google Cloud Storage.', array(
                'objectPath'  => $this->getObjectPath($path, null),
                'filter'      => $filter,
                'bucket'      => $this->bucket,
                'exception'   => $e,
            ));
            throw new NotStorableException('The object could not be created on Google Cloud Storage.', null, $e);
        }
    }    

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function remove(array $paths, array $filters)
    {
        if (empty($paths) && empty($filters)) {
            return;
        }

        if (empty($paths)) {
            // I don't to do any thing for the moment!!
            // Not urgent for the moment!
            return;
        }

        foreach ($filters as $filter) {
            foreach ($paths as $path) {
                if (!$this->objectExists($path, $filter)) {
                    continue; 
                }

                try {
                    $this->adapter = new \Gaufrette\Adapter\GoogleCloudStorage(
                            $this->service,
                            $this->bucket, array(
                                'directory'=>$this->cachePrefix .'/'. $filter,
                                'acl'=>$this->acl), true);

                    // Creation of the $filesystem
                    $this->filesystem = new \Gaufrette\Filesystem($this->adapter);

                    // the file to be delete is here
                    $f = $this->getObjectUrl($path, $filter);

                    // deleting the file
                    $this->filesystem->delete($path);
                    $this->logger->info('delete(): DONE FOR '.$f);

                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->logError('The object could not be deleted from Google Cloud Storage.', array(
                        'path'        => $path,
                        'filter'      => $filter,
                        'bucket'      => $this->bucket,
                        'exception'   => $e,
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    }    

    /**
     * Returns the object path within the bucket.
     *
     * @param string $path   The base path of the resource.
     * @param string $filter The name of the imagine filter in effect.
     *
     * @return string The path of the object on Google Cloud Storage.
     */
    public function getObjectPath($path, $filter){
        $this->setKeyCachePrefix($path);
        $path= $this->key;
        $path = $this->cachePrefix
            ? sprintf('%s/%s/%s', $this->cachePrefix, $filter, $path)
            : sprintf('%s/%s', $filter, $path);

        return str_replace('//', '/', $path);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the URL for an object saved on Google Cloud Storage.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $filter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getObjectUrl($path, $filter){
        // AWS S3 solution (No need for it!)
        //return $this->storage->getObjectUrl($this->bucket, $path, 0, $this->getOptions);

        // Google Cloud Storage solution 
        return 'https://storage.googleapis.com/' .$this->bucket. '/' . $this->getObjectPath($path, $filter);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether an object exists.
     *
     * @param string $objectPath
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function objectExists($path, $filter){
        // AWS S3 solution... (No need for it!)
        //return $this->storage->doesObjectExist($this->bucket, $objectPath);

        // Google Cloud Storage solution
        $file = $this->getObjectUrl($path, $filter);
        $file_headers = @get_headers($file);
        $this->logger->info("objectExists: file=".$file);
        if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
            $this->logger->info("objectExists: file_headers[0]=". $file_headers[0]);
            $exists = true;
        }
        else {
            $this->logger->info("objectExists: file_headers[0]=". $file_headers[0]);
            $exists = false;
        }
        return $exists;
    } 
    /**
     * @param mixed $message
     * @param array $context
     */
    protected function logError($message, array $context = array())
    {
        if ($this->logger) {
            $this->logger->error($message, $context);
        }
    }    
}
```

Here is my custom StreamLoader:

```
<?php

namespace Minn\AdsBundle\Loader;

//use Imagine\Image\ImagineInterface;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Data\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Exception\Binary\Loader\NotLoadableException;

class GCSStreamLoader implements LoaderInterface{

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /*
     * @var ImagineInterface
     */
    //protected $imagine; 

    /**
     * The wrapper prefix to append to the path to be loaded.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $wrapperPrefix;

    /**
     * A stream context resource to use.
     *
     * @var resource|null
     */
    protected $context;


    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param string          $wrapperPrefix
     * @param resource|null   $context
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger/*, ImagineInterface $imagine*/, $wrapperPrefix, $context = null){

        $this->logger = $logger;
        /*$this->imagine= $imagine;*/

        $this->logger->notice("*************__construct (StreamLoader)*********************");
        $this->wrapperPrefix = $wrapperPrefix;
        $this->logger->notice("__construct: wrapperPrefix=$wrapperPrefix");
        $this->logger->notice("__construct: context=$context");
        if ($context && !is_resource($context)) {
            $this->logger->notice("__construct: InvalidArgumentException!!!");
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The given context is no valid resource.');
        }

        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */    
    public function find($path)
    {
        $name = $this->wrapperPrefix.$path;

        /*
         * This looks strange, but at least in PHP 5.3.8 it will raise an E_WARNING if the 4th parameter is null.
         * fopen() will be called only once with the correct arguments.
         *
         * The error suppression is solely to determine whether the file exists.
         * file_exists() is not used as not all wrappers support stat() to actually check for existing resources.
         */
        if (($this->context && !$resource = @fopen($name, 'r', null, $this->context)) || !$resource = @fopen($name, 'r')) {
            $this->logger->notice("find: NotLoadableException (3)!!! Source image %s not found".$name);
            throw new NotLoadableException(sprintf('Source image %s not found.', $name));
        }

        // Closing the opened stream to avoid locking of the resource to find.
        fclose($resource);

        try {
            $content = file_get_contents($name, null, $this->context);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->notice("find: NotLoadableException (2)!!! Source image %s could not be loaded". $name);
            throw new NotLoadableException(sprintf('Source image %s could not be loaded.', $name, $e));
        }

        if (false === $content) {
            $this->logger->notice("find: NotLoadableException (3)!!! Source image %s could not be loaded". $name);
            throw new NotLoadableException(sprintf('Source image %s could not be loaded.', $name));
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try to get a file from Google Cloud Storage only using Gaufrette, does it work? Anyway, see the logs of your app to understand which exactly is the error. Also, read this, maybe it will help you (also if it is for AWS S3): http://aerendir.me/2016/01/25/how-to-use-liipimaginebundle-to-manage-thumbnails-through-amazon-s3/

Comment: Thank you very much for you proposal. May be I will move to AWS S3.